# Tensorflow installation on Windows 64bit with Python 3.6

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to install Tensorflow on Windows 10 Pro 64 bit with Python 3.6 and pip 18.1 versions. I followed the options given in similar posts and tried with

- pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
- pip install --upgrade tensorflow

Both options giving me the error, "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow"

I also tried to install from the original wheel.

- pip install
  https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

which gave me the error, "tensorflow-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."

Appreciate any help to locate identify the issue here.

Comment: What does the command `python -c "from pip._internal import pep425tags; print(pep425tags.get_supported())"` return?

Comment: You use the wrong wheel, for Python 3.6 you need a wheel with `cp36` not `cp35`. For Python 2.7 you need `cp27`

Comment: Have you solved this? I have the exact same issue and have tried installing many different versions of python

Answer (score 0):

try pip install tensorflow instead of upgrade

Reference https://www.tensorflow.org/install/

Comment: I'm getting the same error "Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow"

Comment: how about you install anaconda 3.6 and then use conda install tensorflow?